# Can I access command prompt through an installation disk without a C drive?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, ssd, backup, external-hard-drive

My C drive can't load into Windows 7 anymore. Any option I choose, advanced, normal, repair, it just says that it's loading windows files and then a black screen. I've read that this is the hard drive failing. I've tried using a Windows 7 installation disk, but it ends up at a black screen with a mouse cursor. I've currently disconnected the C drive.

If I now use the Windows 7 installation disk, will I be able to access the command prompt in order to copy files from my D drive to an external hard drive? I'm thinking at this point I should just reformat the C drive with my Macbook via USB (it's an SSD drive). I've been able to copy over some files from the C drive so far to the Macbook.

Answer (score 1):

Most ESD (Emergency Service Disk) that  Microsoft has  come out with and  install disks for that matter allow  command line  access  via

> 'Shift' + 'D'

this  will drop you to a net user/admin prompt  if you need any unprivledged tasks completed  drop priveledges per  usual methods or  do after the  copy over  is  complete (presumably  from the  then working system).

Comment: From what point should I try 'Shift + D'?

Comment: I tried Shift + D from the Install Windows menu and from the Repair your computer menu. Neither worked. Is there something I'm missing? Edit: Shift + F10 brought up the command

Comment: Shift + F10 brought up the cmd.exe but it says "X:\Sources>". Is there a way to access my D drive?

Comment: try cd /d d:\ for D and cd /d c:\ for the C:\ drive. You should also be able to copy c:\path\someFiles d:\newPath\newFiles.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question you asked: it answers the situation that you're actually trying to deal with.

When booting up Windows, try holding F8.  If that doesn't work, try rapidly tapping F8.  Note that I'm not talking about booting from a CD.  I'm talking about booting from the same hard drive.

Hopefully you'll get a menu that may allow you to access an "Advanced Boot Options" screen.  The "Repair your computer" option in Windows 7 may provide you with a command prompt.  I've been able to do this when Windows just boots a black screen.  Your ability, or non-ability, to do this might depend on what the exact problem is.  Also, in Windows XP, I believe that accessing the Recovery Console may have required installing support ahead of time.  So, although I have had success with this, maybe some installations won't work.  Still, this may be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Similar to what linuxdev proposed, you have to enter Shift + f10 after the installation disk is done loading. You might have to press next first before Shift + f10. Then to access your drive(s) simply type in diskpart and list volume and see what letter the drive(s) you're trying to access has been given. Exit diskpart and then you can use xcopy to copy and backup files from the drive to an external drive you've plugged in via usb.

Example

```
> xcopy "(source directory)" /e "(destination directory)"
```

The /e is for copying every subdirectory as well.